# uWSGI and nginx configuration for multiple flask apps running on different ports on the same server

Tags: api, nginx, flask, configuration, uwsgi

I have multiple small flask apps. I would want to run each of the flask apps on different ports on the same server(single domain).

For example say i have 3 flask apps

1. tasks.py --> has API endpoints with /task only
2. users.py --> has API endpoints with /user only
3. analysis.py --> has API endpoints with /analysis only

domain name : api.test.com

I want to run tasks.py on port 8080 , users.py on port 5000 and analysis.py on say port 4500.

I want to configure my **uWSGI** and **nginx** so that when i hit the **api.test.com/task/xxxx** i want the request to be directed to port **8080** (where tasks.py is running),
similarly **api.test.com/user/xxxx** should be directed to port **5000** and **api.test.com/analysis/xxxx** to **4500**

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you could have one single uWSGI isntance for that with one port, but if you like this way of thinking, then you can follow the next way.

Suppose, you already have several uWSGI instances running on different ports: 8080, 5000 and 4500.
Then you need to create an Nginx config with approximately the following content (read the comments, please):

```
# webserver configuration
server {

    # port to be listened by the web-server
    listen      80;

    # domain name with its aliases or the ip
    server_name   api.test.com;

    # SETUP THREE LOCATION SECTIONS FOR EACH ACTION

    location /task {
        # AND SPECIFY THE NEEDED ADDRESS:PORT HERE
        uwsgi_pass  YOUR_SERVER_IP:8080;

        # ONE MAY ALSO USE UNIX-SOCKET (IF ON THE SAME SERVER), INSTEAD OF A PORT
        # uwsgi_pass unix:/path/to/the/socket.sock

        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # stadard parms with environment variables required by a uwsgi app
    }

    location /user {
        uwsgi_pass  YOUR_SERVER_IP:5000;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /analysis {
        uwsgi_pass  YOUR_SERVER_IP:4500;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I hope, you know, how to run three uWSGI instances for each of the ports.

In my opinion, this is extremely ugly, as in order to add any new action you will have to edit Nginx config again. So I don't recommend this solution and only suggest this answer as demonstration of Nginx's capabilities in connection with other web servers.